# Angular 2/4 Interpolation in Json Object path

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am currently trying to pass in a string into my json path so I can do this:

```
*ngFor = 'let key of sector.{{id}}.batches'
```

but it works when I use a specific id

```
*ngFor = 'let key of sector.NUM1.batches'
```

How do I use string interpolation in this situation?

Comment: How about this: Assuming sector is an array with NUM1, NUM2 and so on..

`<someTag *ngFor="let sec of sector"> {{sec}}
    <someTag *ngFor="let key of sec.batches"> {{key}}</someTag>
</someTag>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to directly manipulate the DOM like that. You'll have to set it up to something static, and then change it in your component.

template:

```
*ngFor = 'let key of sector.selectedID.batches | jsonKeyPipe'
```

component:

```
sector.selectedID: any;

methodThatPreviousSetID(id) {
  this.sector.selectedID = this.sector[id]
}
```